# How can I fix this issue of mismatching IP addresses when using WireGuard tunnel?

Tags: networking, proxy, nginx, tunnel, wireguard

I have set up a WireGuard tunnel between my EC2 instance to my home PC.

I am serving a PHP app on a VM on my PC with nginx via IP `10.0.0.100`

The WireGuard tunnel IPs are `10.8.0.11` for the EC2 instance and `10.8.0.22` for my local PC

I installed nginx on the EC2 instance and I am routing traffic to my PHP app with the following config:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host-Real-IP  $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://10.8.0.22:80;
    }
}
```

My EC2 IP for this example is `34.34.34.34`.

When I type this IP in the browser it works and I actually see the website.

But my app uses some functions that read the server IP, and in my case when I click certain routes that use this functions, it redirects to `http://10.8.0.22/some_route` instead of to `http://34.34.34.34/some_route` (which in turn would proxy pass to the actuall PC)

I was thinking to edit the nginx config on my local PC VM to redirect traffic from `10.8.0.22` to `10.0.0.100` (and not do that on the EC2 to not expose the internal IP)

But how can I do that? I've tried several proxy_pass from my PC to itself (from `10.8.0.22` to `10.0.0.100`) but my syntax failed. Might be because I already have the following in the config and it's colliding:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp;
    root /var/www/myapp/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Edit:
This is `ip route` output on the VM on my PC:

```
default via 10.0.0.138 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.100 metric 100
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.100 metric 100
10.0.0.138 dev enp0s3 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.100 metric 100
10.8.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.22
```

and the output of `route print` on the Windows host: (Note I recently replaced routers and I think it shows the older `192.168.x.x` routes, but currently the new router uses `10.0.x.x`

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.138         10.0.0.1     25
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
         10.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
    192.168.182.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.182.1    291
    192.168.182.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.182.1    291
  192.168.182.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.182.1    291
    192.168.206.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.206.1    291
    192.168.206.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.206.1    291
  192.168.206.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.206.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.182.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.206.1    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.182.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.206.1    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.1    281
===========================================================================
```

And this is the output of `ip route` on the EC2 machine:

```
default via 168.25.75.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 168.25.80.15 metric 100
10.8.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.11
168.25.0.2 via 168.25.75.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 168.25.80.15 metric 100
168.25.75.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 168.25.80.15 metric 100
168.25.75.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 168.25.80.15 metric 100
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish…? Isn't your only problem about the generated URLs? Simply make the application use the correct base URL.

Comment: may want to be explicit about what interface you are binding the server to, so that it only listens on the IPs you want it to.

Comment: @DanielB but I could perhaps pass requests coming to the WireGuard tunnel (10.8.0.2) to the actual machine IP (10.0.0.2) and solve the issue instead of trying to dig into the framework and see where it sets the URL. Also the issue is that if I will be explicit, then it will always redirect to the EC2 IP and then locally it won't work

Comment: @FrankThomas can you explain what do you mean by that, maybe with a simple example? As I am not proficient with nginx

Comment: it sounds like your webserver on prem has bound your website not only to the interface carrying 10.0.0.100, but also to the wireguard interface on 10.8.0.22. first off, you should never actually address traffic to the WG tunnel IPs. that tunnel functions automatically, and you tell traffic to go through it by addressing the network on the other side, so from your local, you access EC2 by sending traffic to the 34.x.y.z network, and from EC you address the local by sending traffic addressed to 10.0.0.x. the IP routes (different from PHP routes) will automatically send traffic through the tunnel

Comment: second, I recommend configuring nginx to listen only on 10.0.0.100. I believe you can do that in your config file by replacing `listen 80;` with `listen 10.0.0.100:80`.

Comment: Understood. But how can I implement that? Because I just tried to change the config of nginx on EC2 from `proxy_pass http://10.8.0.22:80;` to `proxy_pass http://10.0.0.100:80;` but it doesn't work (504 gateway time-out)

Comment: that implies that the IP routing for your network is not adding routes for your VPN connected networks, or there is a firewall in play. Note that this is not about your webserver or your web application, but networking fundementals. please describe to us how you implemented your VPN. are you connecting from your LAN router to a VPN gateway on EC3 (site-to-site) or from your lan host to the EC3 gateway (host-to-site), or is it directly from your lan host to your cloud host (host-to-host). what configuration have you made for IP routing? show us `ip route`  (linux) or `route print` (windows).

Comment: I am running an Ubuntu VM on Windows host, on which one should I run the command?

Comment: @FrankThomas from LAN host to EC2 host I believe

Comment: wow, you are just packing this with maximal complexity, aren't you. the one that has the VPN endpoint, i guess. how is networking set up for your VM? Nat/bridged/host-only/etc ?

Comment: @FrankThomas Haha sorry - I edited the post, added the output to the bottom, I just have a few VMs for development and it really does make everything complex. I am using bridged connection from host to VM. Also forgot to answer your other question - I believe I set it up host to host as can be seen here in "Just a single connection" section (made a simple connection) https://www.stavros.io/posts/how-to-configure-wireguard/

Comment: @FrankThomas update: I also added the output of `ip route` of the EC2 machine to the bottom of the post

Comment: so neither of your endpoints have routes to the remote network on the other side of the tunnel. you need a route from EC2 to 10.0.0.0/24 that uses the wg0 as its interface, and on the VM, you need a route to 168.25.0.0/16 or 168.25.75.0/20 also going through wg0. that way when your system sends a packet from EC to LAN, it addresses it to 10.0.0.100 and per the route, passes it through the tunnel.  if your routers support WG, you may be able to simplify things by using a site-2-site. just a thought though

Comment: Can you please help me with an example on how to add one of these routes and then I'll do the rest? I prefer that you give me the correct command and that I won't start looking up on how to do that and then I might make mistakes on that part

Comment: @FrankThomas By the way, why does it currently work if there are no routes? I mean how does that tunnel work and I see the website (until I use routes). Where in the output of the commands above it shows why some work but some don't?

Comment: OK, so perhaps I'm going overboard. my thought was to "simplify" your networking by making the VPN connection a transparent component, rather than hard-coded dependency in your application server config.  if correctly set up, it would separate the concerns of the application from the concerns of the VPN connection, and let you get down to brass tacks on the application issue. I think the issue you are having with your app is that its listening on multiple interfaces, and can thus return inconsistent IP addresses.

Comment: so you can continue to use the tunnel endpoint if you want, since that is probably easier. I do think you should avoid any function that uses a local IP, instead favoring a DNS name instead, but that too adds some complexity. that said it should solve your issue, since DNS names can resolve to IPs based on the clients location, and lets you send redirects back to the client that make sense to IT, even when they can't connect to your back end server. redirect to IPs really won't work in many web apps when a reverse proxy is in use, as seems to be your goal.

Comment: @FrankThomas, I found another way which works for me. I might've confused you with how I wrote the question. But in my case all I had to do was to add `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to the nginx config on EC2. This way, my PHP app generates URLs based on the actual host (The EC2 public IP) and not the proxied host (the WireGuard tunnel), and so, every base URL now is the EC2 public IP and then the rest of the nginx config proxies request as it did before

Comment: glad you got a solution that works for you. cheers!

Comment: @B.DLiroy Please use your last comment to write an answer to your question

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you for the help. David I'm soon writing an answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - the problem in my case was that the framework (Laravel) uses the HTTP Host header to build URLs. When I specify a `proxy_pass` header, nginx defaults to re-writing the Host header to use the `proxy_host`, not the original host. So the HTTP requests to the webserver contains `Host: 10.8.0.22`.

In order to get the external IPs as the host, I had to rewrite the header using `proxy_set_header Host $host;`

With the following updated nginx config on the EC2 instance, now URLs are generated correctly with the EC2 public IP:

```
server {

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host-Real-IP  $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://10.8.0.22:80;
    }
}
```